# Страницы в Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите как реализовать страницы с перелистыванием вперед и назад как показано на гифке. введите сюда описание изображения

Покажите пример для двух страниц, пожалуйста!

```
instruction_caption = (
    'step 1',
    'step 2',
    'step 3',
    'step 4',
    'step 5',
    'step 6',
    'step 7',
    'step 8'
)


# При изменении сообщения мы каждый раз будем создавать новые кнопки с обновленным callback_data
def btn_nextback(page):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    next = types.InlineKeyboardButton('➡️', callback_data=f'pages_{page + 1}')
    back = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅️', callback_data=f'pages_{page - 1}')
    return markup.add(back, next)


@dp.message_handler(commands='test')
async def cmd_pages(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.chat.id, instruction_caption[0], reply_markup=btn_nextback(1))


# Если callback ловит данные с pages_ мы сплитуем и достаем индекс кнопки что = индексу шага.
async def next_(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if (call.data.startswith('pages_')):
        page = int(call.data.split('_')[1])
        await call.message.edit_text(instruction_caption[page - 1], reply_markup=btn_nextback(page))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вам мешает сделать кнопки "page_plus" и "page_minus"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
instruction_caption = (
    'step 1',
    'step 2',
    'step 3',
    'step 4',
    'step 5',
    'step 6',
    'step 7',
    'step 8'
)

def construct_keyboard(data: tuple, page: int) -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    length=len(data)
    kb={'inline_keyboard': []}
    buttons=[]
    if page > 1: #убираем возможность уйти в минус
        buttons.append({'text':'<-', 'callback_data':f'page_{page-1}'})
    #от меня: номер страницы) 
    buttons.append({'text':f'{page}/{length}', 'callback_data':'none'})
    if page < length: #проверка чтобы не выйти за границы листа
        buttons.append({'text':'->', 'callback_data':f'page_{page+1}'}) 
    kb['inline_keyboard'].append(buttons)
    return kb

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    text=instruction_caption[0]
    await message.answer(text, reply_markup=construct_keyboard(instruction_caption, 1)) 

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='page_')
async def page(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    page=int(call.data.split('_')[1])
    #получаем номер страницы
    text=instruction_caption[page-1]
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(
        text, 
        reply_markup=construct_keyboard(instruction_caption, page))
```

Этот пример динамичен, работает от одной страницы до бесконечности)

Comment: ошибки при запуске

Comment: Может, текст ошибки дадите?) Я вроде нашёл опечатку, перекопируйте мой код ещё раз, но если что-то ещё возникнет - напишите текст ошибки

Comment: closing parenthesis ')' does not match opening parenthesis '{'

Comment: Исправил, перекопируйте текст

Comment: все равно также

Comment: 4 ошибки выходит

Comment: Нашёл в ещё одном месте и исправил

Comment: @biflé нет не исправил, но я добавил

Comment: Я ответ с телефона писал, несколько скобок потерял) Спасибки что исправил

Comment: бро ты лучший) скажи а в кортеж можно засунуть картинку, аудио и текст?

Comment: @biflé единственное до чего хотел бы дое* так это то что вместо обьектов типа `InlineKeyboardMarkup/Button` юзаются словари, что немного ломает понимание кода

Comment: Можно, но вроде же нельзя аудио с фото присылать одновременно?) А так можно

Comment: Насчёт словарей - я так привык, сорянчик, да и на мой взгляд упрощает конструирование клавиатуры

Comment: Кстати, если решил вопрос - пометьте мой ответ как решение <3

Comment: ок. скажи а с тобой можно как то связаться?

Comment: Если прям нужно - tg: @le_bifle